Contact Form 7 how to filter dropdown
how to set When a user selects a location from the dropdown in the Contact Form 7 form, the list of doctors will be filtered to show only the doctors in that location. The list will update dynamically without requiring a page reload.
how to set When a user selects a location from the dropdown in the Contact Form 7 form, the list of doctors will be filtered to show only the doctors in that location. The list will update dynamically without requiring a page reload
